# How to order user clean-up in Gherkin+Cucumber+Cypress

Tags: testing, cypress, gherkin

I am writing testing for user-manipulation focused webUI application ([freeipa](https://github.com/freeipa/freeipa-webui)).

I want to test addition of multiple users and then their deletions. For that, I need to make sure that users from previous runs are cleaned, especially since in local development the back-end application keeps running without restart (in Github-CI it spawns for each PR run).

Relevant snippet:

```
 Background:
    Given I am logged in as "admin"
    Given I am on "active-users" page

  Scenario Outline: Add a new user
    When I click on "Add" button
    * I type in the field "User login" text "<userLogin>"
    * I type in the field "First name" text "<firstName>"
    * I type in the field "Last name" text "<lastName>"
    * I type in the field "New Password" text "<password>"
    * I type in the field "Verify password" text "<password>"
    * in the modal dialog I click on "Add" button
    Then I should see "<userLogin>" entry in the data table
    Examples:
      | userLogin | firstName | lastName | password             |
      | testuser1 | Arthur    | Dent     | ILoveKlingonPoetry42 |
      | testuser2 | Banana    | Bread    | FishAndChips097      |
      | testuser3 | Cypress   | Gateway  | TestingIsFun73       |


  Scenario: Delete a user
    Given I should see "testuser1" entry in the data table
    When I select entry "testuser1" in the data table
    And I click on "Delete" button
    Then I see "Remove active users" modal

    When in the modal dialog I check "Delete" radio selector
    And in the modal dialog I click on "Delete" button
    Then I should not see "testuser1" entry in the data table
```

**What I tried:**

- `Before` hook

  - This is executed before `Background` (before admin is logged in), therefore it fails
- putting "clean state" step in the `Background` block

  - this gets executed before every scenario, therefore `Delete a user` fails
- putting "clean state" step as a first step in `Add a new user` scenario:

  - This beats the purpose of having multiple users visible.

How should I refactor/order my tests in order to start `Add a new user` with an empty table, but keep the added users for deletion?
If this violates coupling principle, is it possible viable to re-use scenario in another scenario?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have three example users, can you only run run "clean state" when the the user count equals 3? Or only when `testuser2` and `testuser3` are present, since  `Scenario: Delete a user` will take care of #1.

Place the step last in Background.

---

There is also conditional `Before()` with tags, but I don't think it directly slots into your test suite above (since `Scenario Outline: Add a new user` runs three times).

```js
Before({ tags: "@clean" }, function () {
  loginAdmin()
  cleanState()
})
```

---

The other thing to consider is Cypress/Mocha `before()` as opposed to cucumber `Before()` which is equivalent to `beforeEach()`.

In `cypress/support/e2e.ts`

```js
before(() => {
  loginAdmin()
  cleanState()
})
```

Comment: Using `before` in `e2e.ts` helped me to achieve desired results. Thank you